# How to create sloping lines in CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to generate such image using css and/or bootstrap 4?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a background-image along with linear-gradient?

Comment: I tried this. but lines are ugly

 background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  95deg,
  transparent,
  transparent 10px,
  #E5CEB6 0px,
  #E5CEB6 14px
  );
 height: 200px;

Comment: https://jsbin.com/zokedi/4/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

you can use the repeating-linear-background as seen in here:
https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/

for example to have a similar pattern with the same colors as you have look at the .layer-bg class in the css:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #cecece;
}

.full-size {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


.layer-bg {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    100deg, 
    #000 0, 
    rgba(229, 206, 182, 1) 1px, 
    rgba(229, 206, 182, 1) 5px, 
    #000 6px, 
    #000 18px);
}
```

```html
<div class="full-size layer-bg">
  
</div>
```